# How to import a local version of Google Material Icons .woff2 with Webpack 1.14?

Tags: javascript, node.js, fonts, webpack

I am importing Google Fonts .woff2 files from the same folder without issue, but importing the Material Icon files is proving not to work with the same setup. The .woff2 files simply don't show up in my sources under Developer Tools. I am building my project in Electron.

I have implemented the rest of the setup in accordance with `Method 2` from Google's implementation guide: https://google.github.io/material-design-icons/#icon-font-for-the-web

Is there anything obviously wrong with this? I have also seen a number of `npm` packages to make this easier, but I'm not clear on how any of them make it easier. Thanks for any help you can provide.

**My Webpack font loaders**

```
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.global\.css$/,
        loaders: [
          'style-loader',
          'css-loader?sourceMap'
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /^((?!\.global).)*\.css$/,
        loaders: [
          'style-loader',
          'css-loader?modules&sourceMap&importLoaders=1&localIdentName=[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]'
        ]
      },

      { test: /\.woff(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: 'url?limit=10000&mimetype=application/font-woff' },
      { test: /\.woff2(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: 'url?limit=10000&mimetype=application/font-woff' },
      { test: /\.ttf(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: 'url?limit=10000&mimetype=application/octet-stream' },
      { test: /\.eot(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: 'file' },
      { test: /\.svg(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: 'url?limit=10000&mimetype=image/svg+xml' },
    ]
  },
```

Answer (score 2):

I was fighting with the same problem. Finally I decided to use file-loader instead of url loader and here is the setup that worked for me

webpack file:

```
...
     }, {
         test: /\.woff2$/,
         loader: 'file-loader?name=[name].[ext]'
     }, {
...
```

and then in the css file you can load the font file:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'MyFontName';
    src: url('../path_to_font/font_name.woff2') format('truetype');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

and then you can use your font: `font-family: 'MyFontName';`

What is important with this setup is the `url` in `css` file - **the path to font file has to be relative to `css` file in which you are using your font.**

Comment: Thanks so much! I have been struggling with this for days and was worried I was going to get no replies on this. I really appreciate your help!